# images didn't display in website after deploying

Tags: html, css

why images didn't display in browser after deploying the website even if the folder names and file names are correct ? my website link is https://aquaworld.vercel.app/
I recheck the file names, formats , try once more to deploy
nothing had happen
normal running it works , after deploying it didn't

Comment: Please provide some snippets of code for us to help you to debug.

Comment: It might help to use F12 to open the debug console of your browser, then go to the Network tab to check the http requests and responses. Check for 404 not found, or 503 server error, or not authorised, timeout, etc

Comment: Test with the url for just one image

Comment: Is your web server configured for serving the images? Tell us which server you use, and show the config

Comment: Is there a firewall that might block the images?

Comment: Are the image files readable by all? Folders readable and executable by all?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you edit your post so all the info needed to answer your question is on this page? It makes it a lot easier to help :) Anyway, it looks like your images are returning 404 errors even when accessed directly. Are you sure they've been uploaded?

Comment: Did you update the html? Try refreshing the page with F5, hard refresh: shift F5, or control F5